# AWS Device Farm- Appium Python - Running only collected tests

Tags: pytest, python-appium, aws-device-farm

I need some help regarding the run of the collected tests. So here is my scenario. I have the tests structured like this:

```
tests_folder {
   feature01_tests_folder {
      tests
    }
   feature02_tests_folder {
      tests
    }
}
```

I'm using Appium Python. My issue is that if I collect only one tests folder and then make the bundle zip with all the project, on AWS will run all the tests. So what is the point of collecting only some tests? 
Notes:
Collection was ok. After running the py.test--collect-only feature_01_tests_folder command only the specified tests were collected.

Thanks

Comment: I see that you've asked the same question in the [AWS Device Farm forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=254032&tstart=0). Let's continue the discussion there.

Comment: I would like to continue the discussion there, but no one is answering me.